# Library for asynchronous client to client messaging

Tags: java, jquery, spring, asynchronous

I am currently developing an online game where two players can play against each other (something like Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?). And I would like to implement an asynchronous service so those two players can send asnwers to each other (and I don't want them to wait) but I don't know where to start, what is the best solution for such a problem?

I am using Spring as a backend and pure JSPs and jQuery on frontend. So after little research I came to [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) framework, is this what I want?Or maybe some JS based solution like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) would work too?

Comment: I'd say [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) are the way to go. [Here](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) you'll find a nice page with a compilation of real-time web technologies. Also, you might be better off asking your question at [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Thanks for response, I am thinking about this too but this is nowadays really big topic, so is there any particular framework you would recommend me?

Comment: I'd probably go for Socket.IO. It is a popular library so you'll have no problems getting support.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Apache ActiveMQ http://activemq.apache.org/. Here is Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: So you think JMS would be sufficient to do this task efficiently?

Comment: If you want asynchronous client to client message exchange you need JMS